# how to fetch table records and store in variable in sql server and extract each record

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables
Category(Category_ID,Category_Name,Parent,Category_Tag)
News_Category(ID,News_ID,Category)
News(News_ID,Title,Article,News_Tags)

I want to fetch all Category_Tag from Category Table where News_ID=72. I am using following query in sql server:

```
DECLARE @cat varchar(100)
SET @cat=(select Category_Tag
          from Category
          where Category_ID in(
              select Category 
              from News_Category
              inner join Category on Category.Category_ID = News_Category.Category
              where News_ID=72
              )
          )
```

but this query is not working for me it is showing error as:- Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
.Also i want to extract each single record from the above query to update News table column News_Tags.Suppose the News_Tags column in News table contains value "Tejpal" and the above query returning two values- National and Interbational. then the final value should be stored in News_Tags Column of News Table as Tejpal,National,International

Please help me here

Comment: What do you want to extract each single record into? To do what with?

Comment: After fetching all records, i want to extract each record to update another Table value with the each record.Suppose in the another there is stored "Modi" and the above query is returning two Category_Tag as National and International then the another table should final value as Modi,National,International.Please help me.

Comment: You can use the SELECT INTO to copy the results found into another table. When you say "this query is not working for me", what do you mean? Error message? Expected results not being returned? You might want to edit your question to add more info/sample data

Answer (score 1):

The error here is pretty descriptive. You have declared a scalar variable which is designed to hold a single value, and you are trying to insert multiple rows into that variable.

You need to either do one of two things, either use a temporary table such as

```
DECLARE @Cat TABLE (CategoryTag VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO @Car
SELECT C.Category_Tag
FROM Category C
INNER JOIN News_Category N ON N.Category = C.CategoryID
WHERE N.News_ID = 72
```

or you can concatenate the values to be a single string.

I think in this case you might be looking for the second option which would look something like this. This code is mostly psuedo taking from another script I have, but it should put you on the right track.

```
DECLARE @CategoryTags VARCHAR(1000);

SET @CategoryTags = (
  SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ISNULL(Category_Tag, 'NullTag')
    FROM Category C
    INNER JOIN News_Category N ON N.Category = C.CategoryID
    WHERE N.News_ID = N1.NewsID
    FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR (MAX)')
    ,1,0,'') [Categories]
  FROM News_Category N1
  WHERE N1.News_ID = 72

UPDATE News_Category
  SET NewTags = NewTags + @CategoryTags
WHERE News_ID = 72
```

Comment: your above query is fetching appropriate records but how to fetch each single record. And your below query is returning NULL in any situation.Please help me here.

Comment: your query is fine if there is only one CategoryTag is returning.but if one category_ID of table Category is present two or more times in News_Category table then two Category_Tag should be returned.In this condition your returns error as:--Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') + ISNULL(Category_Tag, 'NullTag')
FROM Category
select @combinedString
```